# permission error to SSH EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I want to SSH to one EC2 instance. I created the key pair using

```
ec2-add-keypair gsg-keypair
```

and change the access using

```
chmod 600 ~/.ec2/id_rsa-gsg-keypair
```

the keypair is:

```
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1610 Nov  2 20:20 id_rsa-gsg2-keypair.pem
```

then I tried to SSH using

```
ssh -i id_rsa-gsg2-keypair.pem ec2-54-205-100-218.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

and it asked me to enter passphrase

```
Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa-gsg2-keypair.pem':
```

and I do not have it. I tried to run it as root user, same error.I used the full path of the keypair file and got the same error. Finally I tried:

```
ssh -v id_rsa-gsg2-keypair.pem ec2-54-205-100-218.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

and got this:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /home/hduser/ec2-api-tools-1.6.11.0/id_rsa-gsg2-keypair.pem: Name or service not known
```

it would be great if you can help me.

Comment: On your second try with ssh, you forgot the `-i`. Did you add this keypair before or after you created the instance? Is this a key you created?

Comment: I created the key before I launched the instance. I just used -v to see how it is working!

Comment: You need to use username in host. `ubuntu@ec2-54-205-100-218.compute-1.amazonaws.com` for ubuntu AMI. `ec2-user@ec2-54-205-100-218.compute-1.amazonaws.com` for Amazon Linux AMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly i would suggest to keep `permission of the key file as 400` as it's too open. If your ami is ubuntu, then `user name for ssh login should be ubuntu`.

so the command would be like `ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@ec2-instace-address`

key.pem should contain the entire path to that file /home/ubuntu/.ssh where it's stored or run the above command from .ssh folder.

`

Comment: Seems to work with ssh -i -v key.pem ubuntu@ec2-instace-address initially and then without the -v in subsequent requests.